Why this PMIC has Via between capacitor and PMIC pins?
Why this PMIC has Via between capacitor and PMIC pins?
Does it break the flow?
Is this good layout practices If yes then how?


Are you asking why the circuit board trace from the IC pin to one part of the circuit has been cut, and a wire has been added which connects the IC pin to a different part of the circuit?

Are the red lines pointing at what you are asking?

The design likely has a plane for that signal/power rail, which also acts as a capacitor with the ground plane. Therefore it's a good practice to connect the pin to the plane as close to the pin as possible, so there's minimum inductance.
The capacitor also needs to be close to the pin, but it's internal inductance and resistance are higher than the parallel copper planes, so it's better to optimize the via location.
